# How to add new page in dropdown list ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How to add new page when user click list in dropdown in asp.net will bring to new page. I've tried but it just refresh the page. It doesn't have error but it can't bring to new page when user click more.

```
<tr>
    <th> <input type="checkbox" id="" name="number" value="No" /></th>
    <th> 1 </th>
    <th>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="pd" runat="server" Class="form-pd" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Redirect">
            <asp:ListItem Value="">Calculus</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="">More....</asp:ListItem> 
        </asp:DropDownList> 
    </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> </th> 
</tr>
```

This is the code behind

```
protected void Redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pd.SelectedItem.Text))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Form2.aspx?value=" + pd.SelectedItem.Text);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it to verify what the "if" statement is doing, and whether it's meeting the condition to actually execute the "Response.Redirect" statement?

Comment: Yes, i've debug it only refresh the page @Craig

Comment: So, when you choose an item from the drop-down, what happens in your debug steps?  Does it run the "Redirect()" function?  If so, what is contained within "pd.SelectedItem.Text"?  If the "Redirect()" function is not running, why do you think that is?  (You haven't included your full code behind .... how is the "Redirect()" function actually being called?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so note that a listbox or combo box (dropdownlist) can have 2 values.

There is the "display" value, and then the hidden value.

In most cases this feature is for say a few choices like some hotel or whatever, but when the user selects that value, we then in code behind use the "value" of that choice - which is hidden from the user.

So, we can present a dropdown of some choices, but ALSO have included in that drop down the page we want to navigate to.

So, you can even use the "wizard" to add the items to the dropdown, say like this:

```
<h3>Select Page</h3>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboJumpToPage" runat="server" Width="250px"
    AutoPostBack="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboJumpToPage_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select Web Page</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="~/Grids/FilterDemo.aspx">Edit Hotels</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="~/Grids/Hotels.aspx">New Bookings</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="~/Accounts/Admin.aspx">Admin page</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

So, note how we have the "value" as the URL, and then the text value for the option.

The code behind for this:

```
protected void cboJumpToPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboJumpToPage.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string sJumpURL = cboJumpToPage.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

        Response.Redirect(sJumpURL);

    }
}
```

Now, it not clear if you need/want to pass any more values.

But, the above is a "simple" way to provide a drop down, and when user selects, then we jump to that new URL (page).

We used AutoPostBack=true which means the user does not need/requore to select and THEN hit some button, since autopostback="true" will execute the above code stub on selection due to the autopost-back.

the result say looks like this:

[image]